# PHP include path for apache dynamic virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I have my xampp configured to serve the subfolders of `C:/www/` dynamically as virtual hosts on `*.dev` so that *project-name*.dev has C:/www/*project-name*/ as DocumentRoot. I use the VirtualDocumentRoot directive for this. Now I would like each virtual host to have it's own php include path like C:/includes/*project-name*/. How can I accomplish this dynamically? I know I can use .htaccess files in each document root but I want to be able to just create a new folder in `C:/www/` and start using it, without any other work (Yes, I'm lazy).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is in your directive direct all requests to a php file that will set the path via set_include_path for this file you'd pass in the virtual host name and the php will do the rest something like this, not saying this will work but will get you close.

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com(.+)%
RewriteRule ^(.*).example.com(.*)% redirector.php?sub=$1&file=$2 [L,QSA]
```

redirector.php

```
<? 
    set_include_path("/path/to/folder/$_GET[sub]"); 
    require_once("/path/to/other/folder/$_GET[sub]/$_GET[file]");
?>
```